# Refresh a file before loading a jsp

Tags: java, jsp

In a project I use a file to read data, when I launch a research for exemple my jsp page is load but the file is not yet refresh and i have the old result. I have to reload the data manualy in the table. I don't know how to refresh the file before the jsp loading.

```
    // research

    FileWriter fileJSON;
    try {
        fileJSON = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\.....\\myFile");
        fileJSON.write(array.toString()); //array is a JSONArray containing the data
        fileJSON.flush();
        fileJSON.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    request.setAttribute("search", search);
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(JSPFile.TEST)
            .forward(request, response);
```

The jsp file is loaded and 3s or 4s after the file with data is refreshed. I actually load the data in my jsp with JS after 5s but I can't know if this will always be enough.

I want to know if it's possible to load the jsp only after the refresing of the file ?

Comment: Who is refreshing the datafile?

Comment: Lets make it simple, some one or some process update the datafile and you don't know when the updating is finished, so your jsp file should wait until the datafile is ready. do I get it correctly ?!

Comment: After some days using a setTimeout with an approximative time, I finnaly see that I have an useless flush() and without it works

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the data file is big and takes time to load. As of now the data file takes 3-4 seconds to load(so using JS you are loading the file after 5 seconds), but you are worried that in future this datafile load time may increase.

If above is right, you can keep polling the data from the file using JS/Ajax after some interval.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller after the flush is end use web socket to send sign to the page to refresh it  self. the following tutorial must help you in understanding the web socket in more detail http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

Comment: By reading your answer I realise that I use flush(), I have deleted this line and it works. Now when my jsp is loaded the file is already refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

After some days using a setTimeout with an approximative time, I finaly see that I have an useless flush() and without it works